# Disable Microsoft Office for one user

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ms-office, defaults

I share a Macbook Pro with another user (we are both Admins). The other user has a Microsoft Office 2016 account, and I do not.

I work with a lot of CSV files, and it's extremely annoying that MS Office insists on being the default for loading CSV. I keep setting SublimeText to be default for CSV, and LibreOffice or Numbers for XLS/X files, but Excel doesn't get the hint. I have changed the settings to allow Apps from any source to open files.

To make it worse, I can't simply Force Quit on the toolbar icon, I have to X-out of the Excel pop-up.

**I'd like to do one of the following:**

1. Remove Microsoft Office for my account
2. Disable Microsoft Office for my account
3. Reliably set another program (SublimeText) to be my CSV editor, and LibreOffice to be my XLS/X editor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you changing the default application for CSV and XLS? Does it not work at all or only until the other user starts Excel once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set a default application for a certain extension specific to a user. Right click on a file, click "Get Info" and open the section "Open With". Select your preferred application and click "Change all".

Alternatively you should be able to delete Excel from your Applications folder (drag to Trash).

Comment: I don't think the other user likes the proposal to delete Excel that much!

Comment: One wonders if you could install Office in the users Applications folder so only they can get to it. Does MS Office offer that option?

Comment: I believe you can install it only for a particular user.

Comment: Indeed with the "Get Info", "Open With" and "Change All" I am able to remove Excel for all CSVs. Thanks!